# Use variable in another method php

Tags: php, function, zend-framework

Could someone tell me how to use a variable from a function in another? in ZEND

```
private $name

public function names(){
           $this -> name = 'John';
    }

    public function leads(){
           $this -> names();
           echo $this -> name;
    }
```

Comment: What's the problem here?  What wrong with this code?  This is part of a `class`, right?  It should work just fine.

Comment: I suggest you read about function arguments ans return values, because your code is far from good example of how to pass data between methods

Comment: I'm using ZEND and therefore send occupied in sight, but first took to pass a variable from one method to another

Answer (score 1):

Option 1: Pass it via parameter:

```
public function somewhereWhereYouCallThoseFunctions() {
    $namePassedToFunction = names();
    leads($namePassedToFunction);
}

public function names(){
       return 'John';
}

public function leads($namePassedToFunction){
       echo $namePassedToFunction;
}
```

Option 2 (without changing your code):

Call function `names()` and then call `leads()`:

```
private class someClass() {
    private $name;

    public function names(){
           $this->name = 'John';
    }

    public function leads(){
           echo $this -> name;
    }
}

$someClass = new someClass();
$someClass->names();
$someClass->leads();
```

Comment: Chain it. `$cls = new Class; $cls->names()->leads();`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy: He'd have to make the `names()` function `return $this;` for that to work.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Oops, yes, that's true. And given the scope of his variables, that's exactly what should happen.